# jQuery loads the content .phtml into a specific <div> (Magento 2)

Tags: javascript, magento2

It is necessary to load via a script content `.phtml > in div`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");
});});
```

I created `testinfo.phtml` (external content-file) 
and created `testcms.phtml`, put code:

```
<?php $TestInfo = $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Cms::testinfo.phtml")->toHtml();?>

<div id="div1"></div>
<button class="testinfo">Get External Content</button>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Cms/js/testinfo": {
            "testinfo": "<?php echo $TestInfo; ?>"
        }
    }
}
```

Created file `testinfo.js` and put code:

```
define(["jquery"], function($) {
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.testinfo').click(function() {
            $("#div1").load( ? ? ? ? ? ? )
        });
    });
});
```

In the `load()` need to place the URL or data. URL string is not working. What need to insert `Data`, I cannot understand. I need your advice.

Comment: `.load()` does require the URL.  Did you enclose it in quotes?

Comment: I quoted. I tried in different ways.

Comment: Try using an absolute URL, just to rule out getting the file location wrong.

Comment: No, it don't work. It is appended numeric value to the URL. 404-page. I'll try a Imperative method.